# FormsAuthentication non persistent Cookie is not getting expired in MVC 4 Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication

I am trying to create the forms authentication cookie by using the below code. Though this works fine for persistent login non persistent cookie is not getting expired and removed from the browser when i close my browser session. It is still persisted in the browser.

```
public static void SetAuthenticationCookie(string userName, Role role, 
bool isPersistent)
{
 string data = role.RoleName;
 HttpCookie authCookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(userName,isPersistent);
 FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
 FormsAuthenticationTicket newticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
 ticket.Version, ticket.Name, ticket.IssueDate,ticket.Expiration,
 ticket.IsPersistent,data);
  authCookie.Value = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newticket);
  HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);            
}
```

Here is the web.config entry for the forms Authentication

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" cookieless="UseCookies" name=".OneClick" 
  protection="All" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="43200" />
</authentication>
```

Here is the screenshot of the cookie information from browser

[image: Cookie Information]

Is there anything i am missing here? Please let me know

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is right solution. But i found out that even though the cookie expiry is set to previous datetime the forms authentication ticket expiry is set from the web.config making it behave like the persistent cookie. So I tried setting 1 minute as cookie and ticket expiry which makes the cookie and ticket expire after timeout period of 1 minute.

Even though non persistent cookie should expire after the browser session ends. For some reason this cookie is retained untill the forms authentication cookie is expired.

Here is the solution.

```
public static void SetAuthenticationCookie(string userName, Role role, 
                  bool isPersistent)
{
  string data = role.RoleName;
  HttpCookie authCookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(userName, 
  isPersistent);            

  if (!isPersistent)
  {
     authCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30);
  }

 FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket=FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);        
 FormsAuthenticationTicket newticket=
 new FormsAuthenticationTicket(ticket.Version,ticket.Name, ticket.IssueDate,
 authCookie.Expires, ticket.IsPersistent, data);            
 authCookie.Value = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newticket);
 HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);            
}
```

Suggestions or improvements are welcome.

Thanks